# Dynamic 'case' 'when' conditions

Tags: ruby, dynamic-programming

The following function iterates over an array `MASTER_INVENTORY`, and presents choices to buy. Typing `1` buys `Item #1`, Typing `2` buys `Item #2`, Typing `34` buys `Item #34`.

```
def buy_menu()
  choices = ['Go [B]ack']
  i = 1
  MASTER_INVENTORY.each do |obj| 
    choices << "[#{i}] Buy #{obj.name} Price: #{obj.price}"
    i += 1
  end
  choicemap = choices.map { |c| "  #{c}\n" }.join
  puts choicemap
  input = gets.chomp
  case input
  when "b","B"
    main_menu
  when "1"
    buy_item_index(1)
    buy_menu
  when "2"
    buy_item_index(2)
    buy_menu            
  when ...
    ...
  else
    puts "Not a valid input"
    buy_menu
  end        
end
```

How can I dynamically increment `case` `when` options instead of hard-coding them like I did above?

Comment: You can't. `case` construction is for static conditions. It is not the right choice here. If you want to handle what you have, use a function (method).

Comment: @sawa you must be kidding. What about our best friend `eval`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case input.to_i
when 1..choices.count-1
  buy_item_index(input.to_i)
else
  puts "Not a valid input" unless input.downcase == 'b'
end
buy_menu
```

or:

```
if (1..choices.count-1).cover? input.to_i
  buy_item_index(input.to_i)
elsif input.downcase != 'b'
  puts "Not a valid input"
end
buy_menu
```

---

*Update:* one case for all:

```
case input
when 'b', 'B'
  main_menu
when ->(i) { (1..choices.count-1).cover? i.to_i }
  buy_item_index(input.to_i)
  buy_menu
else
  puts "Not a valid input"
  buy_menu
end
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was really helpful!  I implemented a version of your code like in the below:                                                                                                               case input.to_i
            when 1..(choices.count - 1 )
            buy_item_index(input.to_i)
            buy_menu()
        end
        case input
            when "b","B"
            main_menu
        else
            puts "Not a valid input" #unless input.to_i <= choices.count
            buy_menu
        end

Comment: Why for God’s sake do you need 2 `case`s?! This is a code smell.

Comment: For some reason, when I change your code from case input.to_i  to case input   it can't register any of the numbers ex. 1,2,34, etc.  It registers them as an invalid input.  WIth two cases, it ends up working.  I would prefer to have one case, but can't get it to work otherwise

Comment: Thank you!  That's works great!  One small note that for this particular case it needs to be (1..choices.count - 1)  because Go [B]ack is also a choice and so it causes an error if you type in the first number after the numbered list

Comment: `choices.count-1` :: fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
when 1..99
  send("buy_item_index",  input)
end
```

https://repl.it/repls/ChillyPaltryHippopotamus

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it doesn't quite work for me.  It may have something to do with part of the response needs to be in quotes and another without

Comment: @BillBisco "Does not work" is to general. Be more precise. What result do you get? Also note that the solution posted by Rots operates with numeric values, while your original attempt operates on strings.

Comment: The linked repl has a solution for the non-numeric values. It was out of scope of the question so left it from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do things in Ruby. This is one solution :

```
O  = Struct.new(:name, :price)
o1 = O.new('a', 1)
o2 = O.new('b', 2)
o3 = O.new('c', 3)
o4 = O.new('d', 4)
o5 = O.new('e', 5)
MASTER_INVENTORY = [o1, o2, o3, o4, o5]

def buy_item_index(p)
    puts "-----buy #{p}"
end

def main_menu
    puts '-----Main Menu'
end

def prepare_buy_menu_and_case
    choices = ['Go [B]ack']
    i = 1
    MASTER_INVENTORY.each do |obj| 
        choices << "[#{i}] Buy #{obj.name} Price: #{obj.price}"
        i += 1
    end
    @choice_map = choices.join("\n")

    @case_body = ''
    MASTER_INVENTORY.size.times do | number0 |
        number = number0 + 1
        @case_body <<
            "when '#{number}'
                buy_item_index(#{number})
                buy_menu\n"
        puts "when #{number} generated"
    end
    puts "@case_body=#{@case_body}"
end

def buy_menu
    puts @choice_map
    input = gets.chomp

    eval("
    case input
    when 'b', 'B'
        main_menu
    #{@case_body}
    else
        puts 'Not a valid input'
        buy_menu
    end
    ")
end

prepare_buy_menu_and_case
buy_menu
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
t.rb:40: warning: assigned but unused variable - input
when 1 generated
when 2 generated
when 3 generated
when 4 generated
when 5 generated
@case_body=when '1'
                buy_item_index(1)
                buy_menu
when '2'
...
Go [B]ack
[1] Buy a Price: 1
[2] Buy b Price: 2
[3] Buy c Price: 3
[4] Buy d Price: 4
[5] Buy e Price: 5
2
-----buy 2
Go [B]ack
[1] Buy a Price: 1
[2] Buy b Price: 2
[3] Buy c Price: 3
[4] Buy d Price: 4
[5] Buy e Price: 5
5
-----buy 5
Go [B]ack
[1] Buy a Price: 1
[2] Buy b Price: 2
[3] Buy c Price: 3
[4] Buy d Price: 4
[5] Buy e Price: 5
6
Not a valid input
Go [B]ack
[1] Buy a Price: 1
[2] Buy b Price: 2
[3] Buy c Price: 3
[4] Buy d Price: 4
[5] Buy e Price: 5
b
-----Main Menu
$
```

This time, the warning about `assigned but unused variable` can be ignored.

Preparing the menu and the `case` code separately in `prepare_buy_menu_and_case` avoids to recompute them each time `buy_menu` is called.

The initial `puts` are for my comfort and can of course be removed.

Comment: Doesn't it exactly answer what you have asked ? I would appreciate a feedback.

Comment: Hi BernardK  I appreciate your responses. I got a little stuck because I couldn't replicate what you're doing exactly in Cloud9.  I'll take a step back and try implementing your prepare_buy_menu_and_case and see if can get it to work!

Comment: I just tested this and it does work!  I commented out some puts.  It's nice.  Thanks!